# Generating Persian and English PDF using iText on Android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm using `iText 5.5.5` to generate a PDF file containing Persian and English characters, simultaneously. So, I used the following code:

```
document.open();

Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();

BaseFont myFont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/droidNaskh.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font paraFont= new Font(myFont, 12);

p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
p1.setFont(paraFont);
p1.add("متن فارسی همراه با english text");

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(p1);
cell.setBorder(0);
cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
table.addCell(cell);

document.add(table);
```

**However**, the English part of my paragraph (i.e. "english text") is not written in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is using a font with **Full Language Support** of Basic Latin, Persian (Farsi), Western European and Arabic. I found some fonts on [OpenFontLibrary](http://openfontlibrary.org/en/search?query=XB) such as `XB Yagut` and `XB Zar`.